# How to read and classify emojis from tweets?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, sentiment-analysis

Currently I am retrieving tweets (using twitter4j library more on info about it is [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html) and reading them via java console(with getText method).
Now I want read the emoticons from the tweets and analyze them as sad, happy etc.

A tiny part of my java code:

```
String keyword="iphone 6s";
Query query = new Query(keyword);
query.count(Integer.parseInt(txt5.getText()));
QueryResult result;     
            do {
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                  System.out.println(tweet.getText());

                }
```

Can you please explain how can i read the emoticons and classify them?

Comment: There's an implementation of this in NLTK, in python. The code is in github. Maybe it can help you get started. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

I would have to say that, this might help it shows the unicode; theoretically i would from there probably make a some if statements or switch case that would classify each unicode for each face.

-best of luck!

Comment: Instead of using an `if` statement you can automate this by extracting both the unicode and keywords columns. Create a hash map where the keys are the unicode chars, and the value is the keywords. Then you just pass the hash map the unicode emoji and you get a list of what that emoji could be.